# Saving file to folder using file_put_contents() doesn't work

Tags: php, imagecreatefrompng

I have been working on a little PHP script that dynamically creates & saves images in a folder `tmp` (which already exists!) from a base64 string. This is my `save.php` file.

```
// get base-64 string from form
$filteredData = substr($_POST['img_val'], strpos($_POST['img_val'], ",")+1);

// decode string
$unencodedData = base64_decode($filteredData);

// create unique filename
$a = uniqid();

// name, location and file extension
$compfile = '/tmp/' . $a . '.png';

// save image
file_put_contents($compfile, $unencodedData);

// print image
echo '<img src="' . $compfile . '" />';
```

Strangely enough: It will neither create nor render the image on the page, because of the `/tmp/` in my `$compfile` variable. When I remove it, everything works like a charm and the image is being created in the same folder.

Unfortunately, I really want the image to be created in the `/tmp/` folder. Before `$compfile` was a randomly generated filename, and instead was called `/tmp/img.png` I was able to save to create an image by the name `img.png` and save it to the `tmp`.

What am I missing here?

(Thank you for your time.)

Comment: I think you want `"tmp/" . $a . ".png"` instead of `"/tmp/" . $a . ".png"`. It's good practice to just always use absolute paths, so: `__DIR__ . "/tmp/" . $a . ".png"`. This takes away any confusion.

Comment: checked the return value of file_put_contents. It returns boolean false on failure, or the number of bytes written otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I guess this was the solution I'll post it as answer.

I think you want `"tmp/" . $a . ".png"` instead of `"/tmp/" . $a . ".png"`. It's good practice to just always use absolute paths, so: `__DIR__ . "/tmp/" . $a . ".png"`. This takes away any confusion.